# Should_panic and expected not working when the message has apostrophes

Tags: unit-testing, rust

My code fails with the message
`"Didn't get a filename"`

But my `should_panic` doesn't detect/match this

```
#[test]
#[should_panic(expected="Didn't get a filename")]
```

yields the results

```
note: panic did not contain expected string
      panic message: `"called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: \"Didn\\\'t get a filename\""`,
 expected substring: `"Didn\'t get a filename"`
```

Obviously the workaround is to avoid diacritics, butI can't work out how to escape the match string.

Comment: Well, I tested `panic!("Didn't get a filename");` on my pc and it worked... Please post a full [MCVE]. I suspect your function doesn't return `Didn't get a filename` but returns `\"Didn\\\'t get a filename\"` literally. Try ex. like `expected="\"Didn\\\'t get a filename\""`.

Answer (score 0):

`Result::unwrap()` requires that the error type implements `Debug`. So it uses debug printing when creating the panic message. Which for strings will include surrounding quotes and *escape* certain characters:

```
fn main() {
    let error = "Didn't get a filename";
    println!("normal: {}", error);
    println!("debug : {:?}", error);
}
```

```
normal: Didn't get a filename
debug : "Didn\'t get a filename"
```

It seems to *generally* follow the rules for [`char::escape_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.escape_default).

So the actual string being printed in the panic message includes an additional `\`:

```
#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "Didn\\'t get a filename")]
fn panics() {
    let result: Result<(), &str> = Err("Didn't get a filename");
    result.unwrap();
}
```